# How to downgrade gthumb in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, downgrade, gthumb

I greatly dislike the user interface changes between the version of gthumb in 16.04 and the version that was in 14.04.  But the deal breaker is this "loading original image" dialog box that pops up whenever you try to edit anything, takes forever, and cannot be dismissed.

Can I revert to the version of gthumb from 14.04?  And if so, how?

Comment: thank you for the question - the new gthumb is really awful!

Comment: It seems like in 18.04 the "loading original image" problem isn't present. But I still like the old user interface better. I hate how you can't right click and move an image from the viewing screen - you have to go back to the gallery to do it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fascinating, people are mostly after upgrades rather than downgrades! In your case you want to revert from Xenial's version 3.4.3 to Trusty's version 3.3.1 which is easy enough to do with a few *relatively* straightforward steps:

### Activate *Sources*

Give access to the Sources used to build the gthumb package by following the trail below and clicking on the *Source Code* box at *Dash → Software & Updates → Ubuntu Software → Source Code*.

Close and allow to reload. Then install the build dependencies for gthumb:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gthumb
```

### Download and build gthumb

Copy the following and paste complete in a Terminal window for a semi-automated download, compile and install:

```sh
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
NEW_PATH="$HOME/Desktop/gthumb_build"
mkdir -v "$NEW_PATH"
cd "$NEW_PATH"
wget http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/gnome/sources/gthumb/3.3/gthumb-3.3.1.tar.xz &&
tar xvf gthumb-3.3.1.tar.xz
cd gthumb-3.3.1
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$NEW_PATH" \
     --backup=no --deldoc=yes --pkgname gthumb --pkgversion 3.3.1 \
     --fstrans=no --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default
```

### Pin this particular version

You will need to avoid the newer version being installed over your compiled version next time you run an update. There are a few different ways to accomplish this, easiest way is to run the following:

```sh
echo "gthumb hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

And now the older version will *not* be upgraded with your next system update! A screenshot on my own system with the older version in place:

[image: GThumb screenshot]

### References

- [Ask Ubuntu: How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/57576)

Comment: thank you very much, a convenient and instructive answer! Would be even better without the hardcoded Desktop - I don't have one, on a non-English OS. I will try to edit your answer to address this easier (I just checked it works) ...